# Using a layout other than application.html.erb in ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

How could I create and use a new template instead of application.html.erb in a RoR application? What are the setting that I need to change to have another template?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, all controllers will search for same-named layouts by default inside `/views/layouts` folder with fallback to `application.html.erb`. For example, `UsersController` will search for `users.html.erb`. Anyway, to use other layout add next to your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'custom'
end
```

Comment: You right, but if I want to use `custom.css` and `custom.js` Rails get me `error: Asset filtered out and will not be served: add 'Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( custom.css )' to 'config/initializers/assets.rb' and restart your server`

Comment: I've been looking for an explanation for this. Could you please link to a source? Also, thanks for your solution!